# Find out which hours of the day the most people registered

Tags: ruby

I am working on TOP and there's an assignment task that says, given a list of date time, example:

```
dates = [
  "11/12/08 15:00", "11/12/08 16:05", "11/12/08 17:18", "11/13/08 1:32",
  "11/13/08 16:40", "11/13/08 18:17", "11/13/08 21:19", "11/16/08 11:44",
  "11/16/08 13:54", "11/16/08 20:20", "11/17/08 19:41", "11/19/08 21:56",
  "11/20/08 16:25", "11/23/08 20:44"
]
```

Find out which hours of the day the most people registered.
Using the registration date and time we want to find out what the peak registration hours are

I want to know what is the formula or step by step in calculating it. And this is by the way in ruby

Thanks!

Comment: I edited your answer to convert your portrayal of date-time strings to a valid Ruby object, namely, an array of strings. This allows those offering answers to simply cut-and-paste, rather than performing the conversion that I did. Moreover, I assigned a variable name to the array so that readers can refer to that variable (`dates`) in answers and comments without having to define it. In general, when giving an example please make all inputs valid Ruby objects and assign a variable to each, and, importantly, show your desired result (as a valid Ruby object).

Comment: If `dates = ["11/12/08 15:00", "11/13/08 15:05"]` is the maximum number of people registering in the same hour 1 or 2?. Tom assumed it is 1, the maximum number of people registering in the same hour *on the same day*; Jamie assumed it is 2, the maximum number of people registering in the same hour *of the day*. Which is it? Please clarify (with an edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve this. Here's one: Map each date to a string that only contains the year/month/day/hour (i.e. not the minutes or seconds), then [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) the results. You can then look at which result is most common (or whatever else you'd like to know about the aggregated data).

```
dates
  .map { |date| DateTime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') }
  .tally
```

Comment: In addition to parsing `date`, you also have to extract the time-part(s) you’re interested in, e.g. _hour_. And for recent dates, the docs suggest `Time` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: I believe you are aggregating by date, hour *and minute*. I think you need `dates.map { |date| DateTime.strptime(date[/[^:]+/], '%m/%d/%Y %H') }.tally.max_by {|_,v| v.size} #=> [#<DateTime: 0008-11-12T15:00:00+00:00 ((1724296j,54000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

If your date format is always the same and you want the most common hour of the day (not caring over how many days),

then you can do

`dates.group_by {|s| s.match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} (\d{1,2}):\d{1,2}/)[1]}.max_by {|k,v| v.size}[0]`

That literally just loops through all your dates, grouping times with the same hour together, then picks out the most common hour

edit: Or to make it more readable using DateTime from Tom Lord's answer:

`dates.group_by {|date| DateTime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }.max_by {|k,v| v.size}[0]`

Comment: Awesome. i realize i can also use count = Hash.new(0) then count[date_here] += 1 but thanks!

Comment: Good job. You could alternatively write, `dates.group_by { |s| s[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} (\d{1,2}):\d{1,2}/, 1] }.max_by...` or perhaps just `dates.group_by { |s| s[/ (\d{1,2}):/, 1] }.max_by...`, the first character in `/ (\d{1,2}):/` being a space.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to find the hour of the day during which there were the greatest number of registrants, taken over all dates in `dates`.

**Step 1: Use [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) to map hours to numbers of registrants**

```
h = dates.map { |date| date[/\d+(?=:)/] }.tally
  #=> {"15"=>1, "16"=>3, "17"=>1, "1"=>1, "18"=>1, "21"=>2, "11"=>1,
  #    "13"=>1, "20"=>2, "19"=>1}
```

The regular expression `/\d+(?=:)/` reads, "match one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) that are immediately followed by a colon, `(?=:)` being a *positive lookahead*".

The intermediate calculation was:

```
dates.map { |date| date[/\d+(?=:)/] }
  #=> ["15", "16", "17", "1", "16", "18", "21", "11", "13", "20",
  #    "19", "21", "16", "20"]
```

`tally` made its debut in Ruby v.2.7. To support earlier versions replace `tally` with

```
each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
```

**Step 2: Use [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to determine the maximum number of registrants by hour**

```
peak_nbr = h.max_by(&:last).last
  #=> 3
```

This shows the maximum number of registrants per hour was `3`.

The intermediate calculation was:

```
h.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["16", 3]
```

If one wanted only *any* hour having the maximum number of registrants (even it their were ties for hours having the most registrants), one could simply stop with this intermediate calculation.

**Step 3: Use [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) to determine the hours having `peak_nbr` registrants**

```
h.select { |_hr,nbr| nbr == peak_nbr }
  #=> {"16"=>3}
```

This shows `"16"` was the only hour having the maximum number of registrants (`3`). Had there also been `3` registrants in, say, hour `"12"`, this hash would have been `{"16"=>3, "12"=>3}`. To obtain just the peak hour(s), write

```
h.select { |_hr,nbr| nbr == peak_nbr }.keys
  #=> ["16"]
```

I wrote the first block variable `_hr`, the underscore signalling to the reader that that block variable is not used in the block calculation. This is common practice (as is using just `_` as the variable name).